# Derefence a vector of references in Rust

Tags: rust, borrowing

If I have a vector of references, I can do this:

```rust
references.into_iter().map(|x| *x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Is there a short-hand that does this? This would be easy to answer with [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/)-like search engine but I can't find one for Rust.

Relatedly, I'd be also curious if there is a shorthand for the opposite operation:

```rust
objects.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

Comment: You can replace `map(|x| *x)` with `copied()` but that's barely any shorter. Also, you don't need the explicit `::<Vec<_>>` turbofish if you're really returning it from the function, which will by necessity have the return type spelled out. With those combined, you can just `return references.into_iter().copied().collect()`, which _is_ visibly shorter, but probably still not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: That's pretty good, thanks @user4815162342!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably no operation *exactly* like the one you want. You can `clone()` the vector, but that will just give you another vector with the same references. If you want to transform the vector elements, you're supposed to do that with the iterator interface because, after all, you might not want to save the results into a vector. And if you do want the results in a vector - well, that's what `collect()` is for.

Having said the above, here are some ways to make it shorter:

- You can replace `map(|x| *x)` with `copied()`.
- If you're returning the vector from the function, you don't need the explicit `::<Vec<_>>` "turbofish" because the function will have the return type spelled out, and Rust will be able to infer it.
- You don't even need explicit `return` if it's the last expression in your function.

Combining the above, you can replace `return references.into_iter().map(|x| *x).collect::<Vec<_>>();` with `references.into_iter().copied().collect()`, which is visibly shorter, though perhaps not exactly what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trait that provides a convenience method on `Vec`s which performs this function for you:

```rust
trait CloneRefs<T> {
    fn clone_refs(&self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl<T> CloneRefs<T> for [&T] where T: Clone {
    fn clone_refs(&self) -> Vec<T> {
        self.into_iter().map(|&x| x.clone()).collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let refs = vec![&1, &2, &3];
    let owned = refs.clone_refs(); // compiles
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f1a550f5aeab546f5ff406e77989a74)

Note: since the `Copy` trait requires `Clone` the above will work for all `Clone` and `Copy` types.

Answer (score 0):

The [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools) crate has a method [`collect_vec`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.collect_vec) that allows you to get rid of the turbofish syntax:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

references.into_iter().map(|x| *x).collect_vec()
```

With type inference, it is sometimes possible to use `collect` directly as well.  Admittedly, the improvement is minimal.